# I want 'hidden ranks' on my employee page

Tags: mysql, sql, select, in-operator

Okay, so my English is not that good and my PHP skills are even worse. It'll be exciting to see if anyone even get what I so desperately need help with.

So I have 11 ranks in my MySQL database. Administrator, super moderator, moderator, etc..

I'm using the SELECT statement in my employee web page. It looks something like this:

```
SELECT id,name FROM ranks WHERE id = '5' AND id = '10' ORDER BY id DESC
```

It doesn't work. What I want to do is to only show employees ranked either 5 or 10. No other rank should appear on this page. What do I do?

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Change `and` to `or`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you used AND instead of OR what you need to be doing is

```
SELECT id,name FROM ranks WHERE id = '5' OR id = '10' ORDER BY id DESC
```

edit otherwise it will be looking for a user with the rank 5 and 10.

Comment: is rank same with id I did not know this.

Comment: It only shows users with the rank 10? How about if I want to show all of the users with the min. rank of 5 and the max. rank of 10?

Comment: It worked when I changed 'id' to 'name'. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @elskov Glad to help! edit: It might be a good idea to mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you

Comment: @jacob_b Didn't know you were supposed to do that. Did it now. Better late than never - haha!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT r.id, r.name 
FROM ranks r
WHERE r.id IN (5, 10) 
ORDER BY r.id DESC
```